How do I knit a Rmd file to HTML?
I have a Rmd file open in Rstudio that I am trying to knit into html.
These are the first lines of the file:
---

title: "Project 2"

author: "do not enter your name"

date: "17/04/2024"

output: html_document
---    

When I klick "knit", the console switches to render and then displays the following error:
  |....                                               |   7% [setup]           

processing file: inst65datavizsubfinalplaques.Rmd
  |.........................                          |  48% [unnamed-chunk-4] 
Quitting from lines  at lines 131-135 [unnamed-chunk-4] (xyz.Rmd)
                                                                                                             
Error in `check_for_XQuartz()`:
! X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from www.xquartz.org
Backtrace:
 1. utils::View(year_no_na_df)
 2. utils:::check_for_XQuartz(file.path(R.home("modules"), "R_de.so"))
Warning message:
In in_dir(input_dir(), expr) :
  You changed the working directory to /Users/admin/Desktop/xyz (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to /Users/admin/Desktop. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit
Execution halted
```

My Rmd file has three data visualisations, and plenty of comments.
I tried the knit to html function via the knit button.
I also have this line further down before I load the data.
```{r setup, include=TRUE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
```


There's not much information or codes provided to work on. It seems to be based on some part of your code based on the error. I would suggest deleting some independent chunks of your code then knit it, doing it again until you're finally able to knit it which means the last deleted chunk was the cause of the error.

As the error message is telling you: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from www.xquartz.org.
